# C# Error CS0173 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between X and Y

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to generalize some code using a C# generics. I ran into a problem on the line:

```
T defaultValue = (intList.Count == 1) ? intList[0] : GetDefaultValue(typeParameter);
```

with the error:

```
Error   CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'T [PathToFile(2035)]' and 'T [PathToFile(2058)]'
```

Below is the entire code:

```
   private void ParseMultIndiciedList<T>(int count, params List<T>[] lists)
        {
            foreach (List<T> intList in lists)
            {
                //intList.Count should never be bigger than count
                if (intList.Count > count)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Multi-variable argument indicies do not match");
                }
                //If only 1 variable is assigned to the list, it is considered the default
                Type typeParameter = typeof(T);
                T defaultValue = (intList.Count == 1) ? intList[0] : GetDefaultValue(typeParameter); 
                int intListIntialCount = intList.Count;
                if (intList.Count < count)
                {
                    for (int countOffset = 0; countOffset < count-intListIntialCount; countOffset++)
                    {
                        intList.Add(defaultValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private T GetDefaultValue<T>(Type inputType)
        {
            switch (Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
            {
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(-1, typeof (T));

            }
            return default(T); 
        }
```

I'm having trouble understand what the problem in the compiler is pertaining to the Type object, if I've directed a Type out of the first generic call in ParseMultiIndiciedList shouldn't I be Ok in the second generic method call to GetDefaultValue?

Comment: Have you tried changing the conditional line to:

Comment: What happens if you explicitly call `GetDefaultValue<T>`, without leaving it up to inference?

Comment: T defaultValue = (intList.Count == 1) ? intList[0] : GetDefaultValue<T>(typeParameter);

Comment: Sorry about multiple comments but commenting from SO app is somewhat tricky.

Comment: @Hassan calling the method with the type like `GetDefaultValue<T>(typeParameter)` was the solution in terms of compiling correctly, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This significantly reduced code reproduces the same issue:

```
private void Foo<T>(List<T> intList)
{
    Type typeParameter = typeof(T);

    T defaultValue = (intList.Count == 1) ? intList[0] : GetDefaultValue(typeParameter);
}

private T GetDefaultValue<T>(Type inputType)
{
    return default(T);
}
```

And yields not one, but two compiler errors (just as the original code did). The relevant one, apart from the one you mention in your question:

> CS0411    The type arguments for method `GetDefaultValue<T>(Type)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

This is because the compiler can't infer what `T` you want to pass to `GetDefaultValue<T>()` (because it's not used as a parameter type). Even though both are called `T`, they have no relation whatsoever, since they're specified on separate methods.

So in order to fix this, you'll have to pass the type argument for `T` explicitly:

```
GetDefaultValue<T>(typeParameter);
```

Now you tell that `GetDefaultValue()`'s generic argument `T` should be fed from `Foo()`'s `T`.

---

The error would be clearer if you'd rename the `T`s:

```
private void Foo<TListItem>(List<TListItem> intList)
private TValue GetDefaultValue<TValue>(Type inputType)
```

Now the error would read:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'TListItem' and 'TValue '

And it'd be clear that they're two totally unrelated generic parameters.

But I'd consider a redesign altogether. The error in your question mentions that you're at line 2000 (!) of this code file, which is a maintenance disaster waiting to happen.

Put these two methods in their own class, and give it one type parameter. Then `GetDefaultValue()` can lose the `T` and use that of its containing class:

```
public class MultIndicedListParser<T>
{
    public void Parse(int count, params List<T>[] lists)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private T GetDefaultValue(Type inputType)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion for making the generic a type in its own class. Also, the Type parameter for GetDefaultValue was omitted altogether, since the type can be inferred through T using the static methods in .NET for Type. Note that a switch structure was used in the original code to indicate an **application specific** default value, in this case an Int32 is represented as -1. I realize that there could be context for this in a static/global context within the application but we are planning to deprecate certain areas in the near future.

Comment: can you edit the post to bold the **you'll have to pass it explicitly:** part? It will make the solution perhaps more clear for people just surfing for a quick fix

Comment: @Rice I don't really like bold text, see edit where I added some whitespace and a horizontal line to separate the extra info from the actual answer. Clearer?

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster!

Answer (score 2):

The type parameter `T` in `ParseMultIndiciedList<T>` declaration is independent of type parameter `T` in `GetDefaultValue<T>` declaration. Therefore you need to explicitly pass type when calling `GetDefaultValue` from `ParseMultIndiciedList`:

```
T defaultValue = (intList.Count == 1) ? intList[0] : GetDefaultValue<T>(typeParameter);
                                                                    ^^^
```

Comment: Should not be T inferred because the explicit value type?

Comment: `T` is inferred, just not correctly. This may be a regression in recent versions of the compiler; IIRC earlier ones didn't try to figure out cases like these and just gave an error that you needed to specify. The current error is one of confusion.

Comment: _"Assuming class containing [...] is not generic"_ - doesn't matter. A method declared with type parameters will hide those of the containing class with the same name. `void Foo<T>()` in `class Bar<T>` will use a different `T` for `Foo()` than the one specified in `Bar<T>`. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0693

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting shows that it's confused about what the return type of function might be in else part. If you add type information while calling that function it should be fine.

```
T defaultValue = (intList.Count == 1) ? intList[0] : GetDefaultValue<T>(typeParameter);
```

The above change should resolve the issue.

Comment: Glad your issue got resolved and thanks for the vote. Was on mobile so could not give the detailed reasoning hence the quick fix. The other answers provide good detail on the issue though which is good.